# Uploaded files on Apache24 Windows server are corrupted

Tags: apache, perl, upload, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script to upload files on my local Windows 10 machine running Apache24. The uploads seem to work fine but the MP3 and JPG files I'm testing with are corrupted.

I've also noticed text files are uploaded with extra line breaks in them, which I gather is a clue of some kind. The text files are otherwise readable.

I've based my script on [Noah Petherbridge's progress bar script](https://www.kirsle.net/simple-perl-uploader-with-progress-bar). That seems to work fine if I run it on an external server, but not on my local Windows server.

I don't know if I should post the entire script here, but here's the meaningful part.

```
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp "fatalsToBrowser";
my $q = new CGI (\&hook);

 sub hook {
        my ($filename,$buffer,$bytes_read,$file) = @_;

    $filename = $q->param("incoming");
    $handle   = $q->upload("incoming");
   open (FILE, ">/Apache24/htdocs/uploads/$filename") or die "Can't create file: $!";
    
    while (read($handle,$buffer,2048)) {
            print FILE $buffer;
    }
    close (FILE);
}
```

I don't know if this has something to do with my local Apache installation, or the perl script is inserting something. Any thoughts would be appreciated! thank you.

Comment: It's Windows, so the distinction between text and binary files is important.

Comment: Start by reading https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut

Comment: (sounds like you might need to treat all files as binary)

Comment: In your case the files should be open as `open my $fh, '>:raw', $fname` , some reading on [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open) is recommended -- [Reading and writing binary files in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/reading-and-writing-binary-files), [Modern Perl](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/modern-perl-fourth-edition_p1_0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

By default, file reads and writes translate between LF and CR LF line endings on Windows. That makes no sense for files that aren't text files, so this is corrupting your files.

Replace

```perl
open (FILE, ">/Apache24/htdocs/uploads/$filename")
   or die "Can't create file: $!";
```

with

```perl
my $qfn = "/Apache24/htdocs/uploads/$filename";
open( my $fh, ">:raw", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't create file `$qfn`: $!\n" );
```

(The `:raw` is the relevant part. The rest of the changes are just improvements.)